# How to: test parent component's method was invoked from child component callback using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, callback, jestjs, graphql, enzyme

This is Parent component which has a method `updateFindingStatus` which is responsible for calling a graphql mutation:

```
export default function ActionBox() {

  const { markFindingAsFixed } = findingMutations;

  const [markFindingAsFixedMutation] = useMutation(markFindingAsFixed, {
    onCompleted(data) {
      const updatedStatus = data.markFindingAsFixed.workflowStatus;
      handleToastOpen();
    },
  });

  const updateFindingStatus = () => {
    console.log("Function Invoked");
    markFindingAsFixedMutation({
      variables: {
        input: findingID,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <TakeActionMenuButton updateFindingStatus={updateFindingStatus} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

This is child component which has the property `updateFindingStatus` as a callback to the same name method in parent component

```
export function TakeActionMenuButton({ updateFindingStatus }: TakeActionMenuButtonProps) {

  const takeFindingAction = () => {
    updateFindingStatus();
  };

  return (
    <>
          <Button
            onClick={takeFindingAction}
          >
            MARK AS FIXED
          </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is type definition for `TakeActionMenuButtonProps`:

```
export type TakeActionMenuButtonProps = {
  updateFindingStatus: Function;
};
```

I am using `Enzyme` and `Jest` for testing my components in isolation using `shallow` rendering. My question is - How do I test that the `updateFindingStatus` method in parent was called when the button in child was clicked?

Comment: When testing the child assert that passed callback is called. When testing the parent, mock the child button to use a spy on the `onClick` handler and assert the spy was called.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I understand the first part to assert that passed callback is called. Can you please share a rough code snippet for when testing the parent component?